# Naming namespace with same classname

Tags: php, class, namespaces, schema, naming

i have a Namespace Like \Project\User\ with a Class User and \Project\Menu\ with a Class Called Menu.
So if i make an instance i call new \Project\Menu\Menu() but the naming seems bad.

Mabye i call the class name Base (\Project\Menu\Base())?

Or has anyone an idea for a good naming schema .

Iam Coding in PHP.

Comment: Sadly I'm not sure that you're wanting to achieve.  Perhaps an example of code might be helpful to help people understand your question?

Comment: It's bad, because ... ? You can also call the class `\Project\Menu` and put all the subclasses into `\Project\Menu` for example.

Answer (score 0):

namespaces should, mainly, resolve conflicts, for example if you are using lot of libraries.

so it is better to have less namespaces in your case

```
namespace MyProject
{
    class User{}
}
namespace MyProject
{
    class Menu{}
}
```

Comment: The Problem is loading the php file. So the autoloader loads the namespace \Project\Menu\Menu() from that file /project/menu/menu.php or /project/menu/base.php if the classname is Base